# Can I run these appliances with 25A

Tags: electrical, 240v

I'm looking to lease a floor of a building for office purposes but the building owner has placed a cap on current to 25Amp due to limited current available. I'm no expert but he has consulted a professional in the area and after figuring out the important stuff, this is the final requirement that he has agreed to:

- 10 laptops (with external keyboard and mouse)
- one external monitor
- 2 air conditioners (9000btu and 13000 btu)
- 2 fans
- 2 air coolers
- 1 mini fridge
- 1 router for internet
- lights
- misc such as phone charging, etc.

I understand current consumption will vary depending on the product but based on your expert knowledge is this combination doable with 25amp or is it going to be a stretch?

Also this is in high humidity (90%) , generally hot weather (30c) and this is on 240v supply (not sure if this matters).

Your expert opinion will be very much appreciated.

Comment: It'll probably get tight (air conditioning and cooling requires a lot of power usually), but without knowing all the specs (power ratings) it's hard to tell exactly.

Comment: You need to know the power consumption of each device and add them up, anything else is guess work. Once you have that we can answer.

Comment: How will this cap be enforced? By a (total of) 25A circuit breaker, or by measurement? If the former, you might find that the breaker tolerance will give you random trip events.

Comment: While this will probably be fine, consider your options for expansion. If multiple workers start requesting dedicated monitors, or you pick up a printer/copier, what happens then? I don't know you're industry, but there are a lot of extra gadget's that might end up being used. 

It's worth discussing with the landlord if there are any options for expanding your power supply down the road, before it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough information to get a detailed look but we can play with some estimates. I am using watts for power consumption, which we will use to calculate amps at the end:

Some of the items we can guess pretty well:

```
10 laptops (80 watts each)       800 watts
1 external monitor               100 watts
9kBTU air conditioner            1000 watts
13kBTU air conditioner           1400 watts
2 fans (50 watts each)           100 watts
1 mini fridge                    400 watts
internet router                  20 watts
```

That adds up to 3820 watts, or around 16 amps @ 240V.

The other items are harder to know. Lighting depends HUGELY on the amount of space you're trying to light and the type of bulbs. A small office lit with LEDs may use only 100 watts, but a large space using old-fashioned incandescent bulbs will use much much more.

Also, I have no idea what an air cooler is so it's hard to get a value for that.

And obviously your "misc" category could include anything...

But I would say as a rough cut that 25 amps is probably enough, assuming you don't blow your power budget on lighting.

Comment: Those estimates for the AC power usage seem _very_ low.  I would expect the 13KBTU to be using more like 12-16 amps all on its own. edit:  I missed that this was 240v somehow...  Sorry, that's plausible.

Comment: @JPhi1618: obviously it will vary from unit-to-unit but I think my numbers are about right. I am talking about the *running* wattages, not the *starting* wattages which are much higher but brief. E.g. for a unit with an EER of 9.5 (not particularly efficient by modern standards), a 9kBTU unit uses 9000/9.5 = 950 watts, and a 13kBTU unit uses 13000/9.5 = 1370 watts. If you use units with EERs of 11 (pretty good), those numbers would go down to 820 watts and 1200 watts, respectively.

Comment: I guess I edited my comment as you were replying.  American here, assuming 120v.  I missed that the question clearly stated 240v.

Comment: Gotcha. (Although the wattages I have in my answer don't depend on voltage.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have all those devices running at the same time it will be tight. laptops typically take between 1-2A so will leave you with little to play with. A lot will depend on the individual power requirements for each device, without that information it is not really possible to know for sure.

Comment: 2A @ 240VAC (480W, or 480VA at least) would be a heck of a laptop.

Comment: Which laptops use 240 W to 480 W? Most use 65 W or 90 W supplies and need those only during heavy load and charging.

Comment: I think you are confusing DC current and AC current. 2A at 240V would be 480W which is absurd for any computer

Comment: My laptop charger takes 1.5A from the mains, but yes you are correct they will only need a lot of power when charging.

Comment: My mistake, laptop can take up to 1.5A, but at 240V it won't be that much. However a point about charging, surely if the charger has as a transformer it will continually taking that much whether the laptop wants it or not?

Answer (score 0):

First there is not enough information, second this land lizard is a joke! I don't think dedicated monitors count at all if flat screen not old school crt's when the laptop is closed the monitor turns off. 2 AC units this is a total crap shoot because some models with a very high energy rating (seer) can produce more cooling with a higher BTU rating , 2 fans, what size I have some 36" maybe larger in my barn that pull more than some AC units (gotta keep show horses cool). Mini fridge again a crap shoot is this a 18" square dorm unit or something smaller than a full size unit, a router and phone charger are you kidding me 1 ea 100w lightbulb pulls more than both of these combined, lights, if you really want this place and want to make a point a couple of high wattage incandescent or halogen will draw more than 20+ LED lamps, what a crock.